# I took a short break from exercise now I can't do my full set. Has anyone experienced this phenomenon? Do u know what this is about?

Tags: push-ups

My exercise was pushups and the break was just 2 weeks now I'm struggling to get back to doing my routine - 2 sets of 35 reps (5 min break in between).

I managed to do my routine yesterday for first time in 2 weeks (was sick so couldn't exercise) but I tried today and collapsed in pain after tryna do just one rep.

Comment: Are you being literal when you say you "collapsed in pain after tryna do just one rep"?

Comment: yes, but in a pushup sense (im already 10cm from the ground not far to fall)

Comment: to understand, after 2 weeks, yesterday you were able to do your routine, but then today you cant? Like you were able to successfully do your routine yesterday but today you cant do 1 rep? That could be because your muscles atrophied, and are now growing, so they are too sore to workout today but were fine yesterday. Try waiting 48 hours.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known thing called detraining. After a short period which is generally recognized as around a week (But can vary depending on other activity, the prior training of the individual, a host of other factors), you start losing the gains that you have made in training.

Again, general lore is that you lose two days for every one that you are out past your initial week. So, if you took a complete two week break in training, then you have lost approximately three weeks worth of training.

Answer (score -1):

When you take a break from exercise, your muscles atrophy and they lose some of their strength. This is because when you're not using them, your muscles aren't getting the blood flow and oxygen they need to stay healthy. So when you start working out again, it takes a while for your muscles to build back up to their previous strength.

You can help prevent muscle atrophy by doing some light exercises (like walking) even when you're not doing your full set of workouts. This will help keep your muscles healthy and strong so that they don't deteriorate too much when you're taking a break from exercise.